# WordPress plugin for affiliate referral system

Tags: plugins

I want to create an affiliate system on WordPress . What I mean is when "Member A" invite other to join (ex. "Member B") by using the ?referralId=MemberA querystring, then Member A get points or credits, and when Member B invite Member C, then Member B get points. Is there any WordPress plugin that can do that ?

I already tried Affiliate Pro Plus (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/affiliate-pro-plus/) but It's not work as expected. When I try to register Member B using Member A's referral, Member B does not count as Member A downline.

Comment: Could you illustrate the need behind this? I'd be interested in which real world use case this could have. Thanks.

Comment: I want to create a website where member get credits/points by inviting other to register. Check themeforest.net, we can add ?ref=xxx on any url on themforest.net

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't know about a plugin but this can be done easily with just two hooks and callback functions:
First you add the refferer field to the registration form using `register_form` hook:

```
add_action('register_form','show_reff_field');
function show_reff_field(){ ?>
    <input id="ref" type="text" tabindex="20" size="25" value= "<?php if (isset($_GET['ref'])){echo $_GET['ref'];} ?>"  name="ref" readonly="readonly"/>
<?php
}
```

Then you just need to save it using `user_register` hook

```
add_action('user_register', 'register_refferal');

function register_refferal($user_id) {
   $userdata = array();
   $userdata['ID'] = $user_id;
   wp_update_user($userdata);
   $userdata['ref'] = $_POST['ref'];

   if (isset($userdata['ref'])  && !empty($userdata['ref']) && $userdata['ref'] != ""){
        //get reffering user id by his login
        $refuser = get_user_by('login',$userdata['ref']);
        //get current refferial credit that user has
        $current_ref_credit = get_user_meta($refuser->ID, 'ref_credit', true);
        //add credit for the newly created user
        $current_ref_credit[] = $user_id;
        //save the changes
        update_user_meta( $refuser->ID, 'ref_credit', $current_ref_credit);
   }
}
```

So all that is left to do is to let your users share there referral link:

```
http://example.com/wp-login.php?action=register&ref=my_login_name
```

So if my user name was "bainternet" then my referral link would be:

```
http://example.com/wp-login.php?action=register&ref=bainternet
```

and to see how many members are in a users downline here is a simple function which accepts a user ID and returns an array of user ids which he has reffered:

```
function get_user_downline($user_id){
    return $current_ref_credit = get_user_meta($user_id, 'ref_credit', true);
}
```

and its usage is simple:

```
// to echo count of how many user with ID of 24 as reffered:
echo count(get_user_downline(24));

    // to list the users user with ID of 24 as reffered:
<ul>
<?php
    $reffed = get_users(array('orderby' => 'registered', 'include' =>  get_user_downline(24));
    foreach ($blogusers as $user) {
        echo '<li>' . $user->display_name . '</li>';
    }
?>
</ul>
```

So just copy all of this code and you have a plugin for referral system

Comment: Thank you very much for the code provided. I actually trying to avoid coding just in case there are already a plugin that can do that. Your code is good start, now I need to add cookies support (where the ref is stored on cookies for 30 days)

Comment: Take a look at most plugins: They contain 5 lines of code and 50 of comments. What Bainternet wrote is perfect. Nothing more or less needed.

Comment: Excellant work Bainternet.try to implement as a plugin in wordpress site.it'll be helpful to all.

Comment: I have a WP setup where I have a custom pop up login box that users `Social Login Plugin` http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/oa-social-login/ where a user can login with FB or Twitter. So a user never sees standard WP login form. I have tried to access $_GET within the `user_register` action, but it's always empty. Any tips on how it would be possible to get `ref` URL param with a setup like that? Many thanks.

Comment: @dashaluna that plugin uses a remote api so the ref field is not present, in that case you can simply use cookies instead.

Comment: @Bainternet thank you for explaining. I tried with a session but that didn't seem to work. I will dig into sessions more. Thanks again, I know it's hard to know the reason when you can't see a project.. really appreciate your tips!